# How to fix flashing in render?

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender, so I tried using a template to make an intro.
When I watch it in Default mode, there is no flashing in the video. When I render it, suddenly there appears an ennoying flash during the video.

What do I need to change to fix this?

I've uploaded the render here: https://youtu.be/Yts1L_WwUdo

I've also included the .blend file here: [image]

Comment: Hard to tell, are there overlapping objects?

Comment: I don't think so, to be sure I've added the .blend file in the question.

Comment: My initial guess is that your composition is over using the Alpha Over and this can cause some normalization issues to be seem like flickering. I will need to dig deeper trying to find alternative ways.